# Limit Points of a subset of Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $E=\{\frac{k}{n}:n, k \in \mathbb{Z}_+, 1 \leq k \leq n\}$. Show that every rational number in $(0, 1)$ is a limit point of $E$.

$$$$My solution is as follows : For any rational number $\frac{p}{q}\in(0, 1)$, where $p<q$ and $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$ consider the sequence $$a_n=\frac{p(n+1)}{qn}, n \geq q$$. Now as $p<q$, we have $$p(n+1) \leq (q-1)(n+1) = qn-(n-q+1)<qn$$ and so $a_n \in E$ for every $n \geq q$ and we know that this sequence converges to $\frac{p}{q}$ and so $\frac{p}{q}$ is a limit point of $E$.

$$$$Is my proof correct?

Comment: We only have to show that all the rationals in $(0, 1)$ are limit points of $E$.

Comment: But the sequence we have chosen is always greater than $\frac{p}{q}$.

Comment: @user671269 Are you sure? That seems too easy. The rationals are dense in the reals which means any neighborhood of a real number contains a rational number. What you've described as $E$ is the set of rationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I showed a sequence in which each element is not equal to $\frac{p}{q}$ which converges to $\frac{p}{q}$ and so it is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: You might want to explicitly state that $a_n > {p \over q}$ and $a_n \to {p \over q}$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. That the problem itself is a little odd is only a concern that you should check to make sure that you have stated it correctly. But given that, there is no problem with your argument. If someone wants to get pendantic about $a_n$ only being defined for $n\ge q$, you can just define $a_n = \frac12$ for $n < q$. But I doubt that your professor will care.